# DocuSign Logon Screens

Tags: single-sign-on, docusignapi

Our company has recently deployed SSO for DocuSign and the logon screen now contains the Use Company Logon button which is all working properly. I have added an image of our current logon screen here:
[DocuSign Logon Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiV4m.png)

What I am needing to know is how does this screen change when SSO is enforced? I had the impression that the password field would go away and only the blue button would remain.

Second part of the question is the option link for Sign in as a different user and if that screen changes in any way.

Can you please post example screen shots of all logon screens from a fully implemented SSO login process so I can complete my user guides prior to enforcing SSO policy. Please blur or redact any private info please.

Much appreciation in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

When I tried my SSO, it skips the screen you're on and goes directly to the IDP (Okta is what we're using).
I think this is done when you have domain trapping, which forces the user to use SSO with any email address with this domain.

https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/resource_event_files/-docusign_access_management_with_sso_datasheet.pdf

Comment: I have seen this document as a part of the configuration. We use Azure as our IDP. Your implementation obviously has SSO enforced. Is there any pathway for a user to log in as another user at that point? 
I have inherited a situation where all individuals have their own accounts and then small groups have team accounts. I know this is incorrect and should not have been implemented this way but I am trying to secure with the least amount of disruption initially and allow attrition to weed out the team accounts over time.

Comment: You would have to work with DocuSign support to fix this